# How to combine two external resources (here: yahoo) in one plot?

Tags: python, dataframe, seaborn, yahoo-finance, yfinance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBn7x.png)

```
ETH = yf.download("ETH-EUR", start='2009-02-01', end=yesterday)

BTC = yf.download("BTC-EUR", start='2009-02-01', end=yesterday)

sns.barplot(data=ETH.loc\[:,"Volume"\]\
    
    .resample("m").mean().to_frame()\
            .assign(Date=lambda dfa: dfa.index.strftime("%m/%y")), x="Date",y="Volume",ax=ax3, color="coral")
sns.barplot(data=BTC.loc\[:,"Volume"\]\
            .resample("m").mean().to_frame()\
            .assign(Date=lambda dfa: dfa.index.strftime("%m/%y")), ax=ax3, x="Date",y="Volume", color="aqua" )

label3 = ax3.set_xticklabels(ax3.get_xticklabels(), rotation = 90,fontsize=5,alpha=0.5)
ax3.set_title("Bitcoin / ETH", fontsize=7)][1]
```

The Goal is to combine BTC & ETH on the 3rd. subplot (see picture). After 2 days of trying with melt, hue=,ax=,other plots trying to combine the dataframe i need help.

In my opinion its a bit special because i can not create one dataframe by request two different data downloads via yahoo or?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Multiple issues can be acquired with this. `data = yf.download("ETH-EUR BTC-EUR", start="2020-12-01", end=yesterday)`

Comment: @r-beginners ...that was too easy. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDHLs.png)

So i could solve it even its high probably not "the cleanest" way to do so. I `reshaped` and `concat` the data by melting it. The catplot shows the ETH & BTC in one plot.But another problem arises, a catplot can not be assigned to a specific ax. Hence i can not include it as a subplot. Has anybody an idea?

```
  ETH2=pd.DataFrame(ETH.loc[:,"Volume"].resample("M").mean().to_frame().assign(Date=lambda dfa: dfa.index.strftime("%y/%m")))
    Date = ETH2["Date"]
    ETH2.drop(labels=["Date"],axis=1,inplace=True)
    ETH2.insert(0,"Date",Date)
    ETH2.rename(columns={"Volume":"Volume ETH"}, inplace=True)
    BTC2= pd.DataFrame(BTC.loc[:,"Volume"].resample("M").mean().to_frame().assign(Date=lambda dfa: dfa.index.strftime("%y/%m")))
    BTC2.drop(labels=["Date"],axis=1,inplace=True)
    BTC2.rename(columns={"Volume":"Volume BTC"}, inplace=True)
    
    ETH_BTC = pd.concat([ETH2, BTC2],axis=1)
    ETH_BTC = pd.melt(ETH_BTC,id_vars="Date", var_name="Coin", value_name="Volume")
    sns.catplot(x="Date",y="Volume", hue="Coin", data=ETH_BTC,kind="bar",ax=ax3, palette=sns.color_palette(["aqua", "lavender"]))
```

Comment: Solved: sns.barplot(x="Date",y="Volume", hue="Coin", data=ETH_BTC,ax=ax3, palette=sns.color_palette(["aqua", "lavender"]))